# How to reglue stickers that came off laptop?

Tags: adhesive

Contrary to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/15538/what-is-the-right-procedure-to-safely-remove-stickers-from-a-laptop), the Intel sticker came off from my laptop and I want to reglue it. What is the best way or the best glue to stick it back on?

I tried already with instant superglue, but that didn't hold for long and the sticker came back off, leaving ugly glue leftovers on the laptop, impossible (or hard?) to remove.

On a sidenote, I already posted this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1631549/how-to-reglue-stickers-that-came-off-laptop?noredirect=1#comment2492022_1631549), but other users suggest this forum to be more appropriate.

Comment: Epoxy? Double-sided tape? How much heat resistance is going to be in the spot where you want the sticker?

Comment: For a sticker, if more like paper/thin plastic would try something like contact cement or even a thin dab of silicon.

Comment: We should trade. I can't stand all these stickers (printers, monitors, laptops) and do my best to remove them. As far as I'm concerned, they are there only as advertising for the manufacturers. Taking off the Intel sticker doesn't change the chip to an AMD, and taking off the Windows sticker doesn't change the operating system to Linux.

Comment: You can likely get in touch with Intel and get a replacement sticker. They like to advertise and all. Other than that there is no useful purpose for having the sticker.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! @FreeMan, Im sticking it at the same spot it came off, on the bottom left, its not a particular heat spot, feels lukewarm at most.

Comment: @manassehkatz If the Apple logo ever falls off a mac though, then the whole reason for the initial up charge is gone (other than when someone legitimately needs to develop for the closed Apple ecosystem)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You want something 'gummy' rather than hard.

'Superglue' is a hard result, easy to crack away if there's any movement in the finished joint; poor for mis-matched surface types like a thin flexible sticker on a hard substrate.

In contrast anything 'gummy' will retain flexibility & is less likely to release with movement.
A generic contact adhesive will probably be the best bet. The old standard for this [at least in the UK] is Evo Stik. Apply to both faces separately. Allow 10 minutes for it to become almost dry, then join the faces. Be careful with alignment, you don't get two chances. Apply even pressure for a few minutes, then leave at room temperature for 4 to 24 hours to fully cure.

Comment: Don't heat cure by turning the laptop on? :)

Comment: As we don't know the precise glue the OP may use, drying/curing instructions would be best taken from the package labelling. The 24h cure is just a general use case, safe.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, thanks for your answer! One small question still: Im situated in Germany, I already checked Amazon for Evo Stik, is [this the one?](https://www.amazon.de/Evo-Stik-EVOIMPS-Schlag-Adhesive-Small/dp/B002NPTNIK/ref=sr_1_6?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=evo+stik+contact&qid=1615233374&sr=8-6)

Comment: That's the one, bit expensive, though. It's half that price in the UK. I'm sure you can find another contact [or impact] adhesive.